# Problem with Openstack with Multiple Floating IPs using quantum-gateway

Tags: juju, openstack

I'm trying to deploy Openstack with MAAS + Juju. 
I followed the tips from Juju charms page and [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseNotes/OpenStackCharms).
Everything worked fine with a single external network. I had all the necessary charms installed and working ok.
But when I tried to use multiple floating IPs I got stuck.
The [Quantum-gateway charm](https://manage.jujucharms.com/charms/trusty/quantum-gateway) tells to deploy a charm per Floating IP pool. So, the charm should create a separated `l3_agent.ini`. But in practice, it creates nothing at all.

Somebody knows how to procede to deploy Openstack with multiple floating IPs using Juju?